# Not able to play song using Python when compiled from terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

```
import pygame

import time

pygame.mixer.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load('/home/bahara.mp3')

time.sleep(2)

pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

While compiling this code from terminal, no error is thrown, but I am unable to hear any music. But when executed line by line, the code is working fine.

Can you suggest a way to debug this? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and python 2.7.6

Comment: What do you mean *"compiling"*?

Comment: You have no screen. What do you expect?

Comment: Is that a real world example? Because music files are unlikely to reside in `/home/` directly, a normal user won't have the permission to write there. I would expect them in a user's home directory like `/home/xolo/`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe compiling means i have written code in gedit and saved as flie_name.py
now from terminal i am executing it using python file_name.py
this code is executed without any error but am unable to hear any song

but when i am using IDLE python2.7
and executing this code line by line its working perfectly and am able to listen music

Comment: @DirkEschler file path is /home/xolo/bahara.mp3

Comment: Is this because pygame is exiting as your script ends, whereas when you run line by line in a python terminal session pygame remains active? try adding a sleep after you play your file to see if you get some sound. Also, you should be aware that mp3 files don't always work well on pygame (although it sounds like this particular file is ok).

Comment: Be aware that MP3 support is limited. On some systems an unsupported format can crash the program, e.g. Debian Linux. Consider using OGG instead. This is straight from the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pygame requires an active display which you have not initialized. I suggest you try installing and using `mpg123` command line tool.

Install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mpg123
```

Program:

```
import os, time

os.system('mpg123 /home/bahara.mp3')
```

Comment: Malik, while I can see that this would play the file. It's not really answering the question as to why it's not working - it's just another way to play an mp3 file. It also means that the ability to control the file through the pygame music module has been removed. It all depends what xolo is after I guess...

Comment: I already explained that Pygame won't do anything unless a display is initialized. However, if the sole purpose is to play audio, it is more efficient to take this approach.

Comment: OK - fair point! However, he does say that the code works when he enters it in a terminal session which would suggest that the issue is not to do with the display. That said, he's accepted your answer which also suggests that this answer satisfies his needs (and, in which case, I agree with your above comment).

Comment: I was using pygame because it was giving me flexibility to control different actions like stopping a song, play next previous.. very easily.. @malik the method suggested by u worked but using this method can I control different parameters like till what time my song will play, pausing the song etc?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post my earlier comment as an answer because I think it's worth trying if you want to retain pygame's ability to control the music player.

I suspect you're getting no sound because pygame is exiting as your script ends, whereas when you run line by line in a python terminal session pygame remains active. One way you could test this is by adding a loop after you start playing the file e.g. by checking the [get_busy](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.get_busy) status:

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('/home/bahara.mp3')
time.sleep(2)
pygame.mixer.music.play()

while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    print "Song is playing"
    time.sleep(1)
print "Song has finished"
```

Assuming this works, you'll still be able to use pygame's controls to play, pause etc.

Also, please note, as Malik and I have both pointed out, MP3 support is quite limited in pygame so you may want to try converting your files to ogg.

Comment: my basic aim is to control different parameters related to song of mp3 extension as i mentioned above so i selected pygame as one of the method. In your above comments you mentioned that mp3 support is limited what is meant by limited here ? Is there any other good way to play and control mp3 files using python that too without active display?

Comment: "Limited" means that some mp3 files may not play correctly. Converting the files to a format that pygame does handle (such as ogg) means you shouldn't have the risk of some files not playing. Please note, as Malik has already said, running pygame without an active display can reduce its functionality. In particular, I think that means that you wont' be able to capture key presses. How were you intending to control the playback?

Comment: aim is to get text file from google API for the given speech. And from this text file i am mapping intension to just play and stop the song of mp3 format.

Comment: Not sure I understand. What's the relationship between "the given speech" and "the song"? Anyway, we're drifting away from your original question which should have been answered. If you want to stop and start sound files, pygame can do it (but mp3 files may be problematic). You will therefore need to decide if pygame is also appropriate for the rest of your program.

Comment: can i make path /home/xolo/bahara.mp3 as variable path as :

a= bahara, 

 pygame.mixer.music.load('/home/xolo/a.mp3')

any suggestions @elParaguayo

Comment: You can make the path a variable, yes. But in your example, you're not substituting in the variable name, instead it will just look for a file called `a.mp3`. You could do `pygame.mixer.load('/home/xolo/{}.mp3'.format(a))`.